# Pre requisites for a course in Heat Transfer from Fluid Mechanics , for a Mechanical Engineering Bachelors Degree

Tags: fluid-mechanics, heat-transfer

Can anyone please tell me the topics I need to study from **Fluid Mechanics**, specially fluid dynamics  to understand **Heat Transfer** in a better way?

Comment: Do you have any specific chapter that you cannot understand well?

Comment: honestly , its not very specific , our course has just begun and I came  to know that mainly in convection concepts of fluid flow would be required so I just wanted to revise a few topics on fluid flow.

Comment: Your university should list the course prerequisites. Personally I'd bone up on partial differential equations.

Comment: Read the Syllabus for the course. ANY good university will have a syllabus for EVERY course taught…

Comment: @SergeantAfanasiev  https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mechanical-engineering/2-051-introduction-to-heat-transfer-fall-2015/syllabus/

Comment: This looks like an [academic guidance question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/261/1832). Such questions often involve personal choice and can probably be better answered by an adviser or counselor. We do not believe this site's format is well-suited to such questions, which are therefore considered off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fluid mechanics is mostly used in handling convection problem, whether it is forced convection or natural convection. Additionally, on those two problems the concept that is used is mostly dimensionless number (like Re, Gr, Pr, etc.) and that's it, and also boundary layer concept. If there is one concept that you should try to understand, I think try to learn what those dimensionless number tell you about how the fluid behave.

Comment: ,honestly , its not very specific , our course has just begun and I came to know that mainly in **convection** concepts of **fluid flow** would be required so I just wanted to revise a few topics on **fluid flow**.